# Creating new iOS distribution certificate vs downloading existing one?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect

I need to get an iOS distribution certificate in order to push my app to the App Store. I've read the instruction on how to generate your own, but also seen that on the `Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles` section of `developer.apple.com` there's an existing distribution certificate that a previous developer used. Is there any reason to generate my own instead of downloading that existing one?

Comment: Can you get the private key from the previous developer? If not then you will need to create a new certificate.

Comment: What does it mean to get the private key? As far as I know all the developer has is a development certificate. Would that contain the private key? And if I did just create my own, would that work? Can there be multiple people submitting builds to the same app on the store?

Comment: To get a certificate you create a public/private key pair.  You submit the public key via the Apple developer site and they sign it with their private key.  You can then use the certificate with your private key to sign developer builds.   If you don't have the private key then the certificate won't work

Comment: You can have two active developer certificates at a time.   Both are valid

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I'll explain my situation and hopefully you can help me out. I have a project on App Store Connect, and a different developer who's not on our team anymore had a distribution certificate for it (although he didn't push any builds). I need to push builds to it, so I followed the directions here (https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-code-sign-publish-ios-apps/) to create a certificate signing request (CSR), then created the iOS Distribution Certificate, then the Provisioning Profile. Continued...

Comment: I added the new Provisioning Profile to XCode (unchecked 'Automatically Manage Signing'), but when I tried to create a build with Product -> Archive, the build failed with the following error:

Comment: "No profile for team <my team> matching 'match AdHoc <my bundle ID>' found: Xcode couldn't find and provisioning profiles matching 'F7RYPSTSCP/match AdHoc <my bundle ID>'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor."

Comment: I remember somewhere it said my Provisioning Profile was "ineligible", but I can't find where it said that anymore. You mentioned I should try to get the private key from the other dev. Where would he find that private key? Again, I've only ever had a distribution certificate when I've pushed builds to the store, so I'm not sure where a private key would be.
Any insight you have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240881/discussion-between-paulw11-and-gkeenley).